# $T(f)=\alpha f(a)+ \beta f(b)$ on $X=C[a,b]$. Find $||T||$.

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $X=C[a,b]$ be a normed space with $||x||=sup_{[a,b]}|x(t)|$. For some fixed real $\alpha , \beta$, define $T$ on $X$ by $T(f)=\alpha f(a)+ \beta f(b)$. Find $||T||$.

I got $|\alpha+\beta|\leq ||T||\leq |\alpha|+|\beta|$. How to get the exact value of $||T||$? Kindly give some hints or ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both $\alpha = \beta = 0$ then $T = 0$ so $\|T\| = 0$. Assume $\alpha \ne 0$.

You already got this:

$$|T(f)| = |\alpha f(a)+ \beta f(b)| \leq |\alpha||f(a)| + |\beta||f(b)| \leq (|\alpha| + |\beta|)\|f\|_\infty$$

This implies $\|T\|\leq |\alpha| + |\beta|$.

Let's find $f \in C[a,b]$ such that $\|f\|_\infty = 1$ and $T(f) = |\alpha| + |\beta|$.
$\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}$

Take $f$ to be the affine function connecting the points $(a, \sgn\alpha)$ and $(b, \sgn\beta)$:

$$f(x) = \frac{\sgn\beta - \sgn\alpha}{b - a}(x - a) + \sgn\alpha, \quad\forall x \in [a, b]$$

We have $|f(a)| = 1$ and $f([a, b]) \subseteq [-1,1]$ so $\|f\|_\infty = 1$. Also, we have:
$$T(f) = \alpha f(a)+ \beta f(b) = \alpha\sgn\alpha+ \beta\sgn\beta = |\alpha| + |\beta|$$

For $f$ we have: $\|T\|\geq\frac{|T(f)|}{\|f\|_\infty} = |\alpha| + |\beta|$.

Thus $\|T\| = |\alpha| + |\beta|$.